# Running Spotify via wine will only use speakers not play via headphones

Tags: sound, wine, output, spotify

I have Spotify installed under Wine. It currently is trying to use my desktop speakers as the default output device, however I have changed the system settings to use all input and output sound for my headset.

I also configured Wine settings to use my G930 headset for the default audio device.

Now when I play for example YouTube video's it plays great through my headset. But only Spotify installed via Wine is determined to use ONLY my desktop speakers.

Any ideas and thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

[I recommend the native version over the Wine version](http://news.spotify.com/us/2010/07/12/linux/)

**Warning:** [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629/40581)

> **Spotify for Linux**
>
> This is a preview build of Spotify for Linux. As a preview release
>   this version is still unsupported, but we're running it ourselves and
>   will try to make sure it keeps pace with its Mac and Windows siblings.
>
> So how do you get it? We've packaged it for Debian Squeeze/Ubuntu.
>   Debian
>
> ```
> # 1. Add this line to your list of repositories by
> #    adding file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
> #    with the following content:
> deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
>
> # 2. If you want to verify the downloaded packages,
> #    you will need to add our public key
> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59
>
> # 3. Run apt-get update
> sudo apt-get update
>
> # 4. Install spotify!
> sudo apt-get install spotify-client
> ```

<sup>Source: [spotify.com](https://www.spotify.com/uk/download/previews/)</sup>

Comment: Do you have a link to that topic online anywhere? And thanks caffinatedmonkey :D

Comment: The link is in the post.

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey Please be reminded that answers should include the solution, not link to some meta discussion or PR text somewhere else.

Comment: @LiveWireBT this is a solution -- installing the native client will work much better than the Wine one.

Comment: @NikReiman Read again or look at the edits of that answer and you'll find out what I meant.

Comment: @LiveWireBT ah, ok. fair enough, I guess your initial comment mode more sense with the first answer. :)